# Table caption width in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, width, caption

The table on this page has a caption with display: table-caption set.

http://www.petersen-stainless.co.uk/lifting/CE-swage-sockets/stainless-steel-threaded-sockets.html

The HTML is:

```
<table class="product-data">
                <caption>
                    Rated for lifting in accordance with EN 13411-8. WLLs stated based on 90% of wire MBL at a 6:1 factor of safety. All terminals permanently etched with CE mark and batch identification number.
                </caption>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="Product Code">SCM6X3R-EN</td>
                        <td data-th="Wire (mm)">3</td>
                        <td data-th="Thread">M6</td>
                        <td data-th="D (mm)">6.3</td>
                        <td data-th="L (mm)">97.0</td>
                        <td data-th="CT (mm)">47.0</td>
                        <td data-th="WLL 7x19 / 6x19-IWRC">70kg</td>
                        <td data-th="WLL 6x36-IWRC">N/A</td>
                    </tr>                   
                    </tbody>
            </table>`
```

And the css I used:

```
.content .product-data {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 70%
}

.product-data caption {
    display: table-caption;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: none;
}
```

It displays at 100% width of the table in webkit browsers but in firefox it is 100% width of the page.  How can i get this caption to fit properly in firefox?  Is it a bug?  It seems like it shouldnt be behaving this way.  If so are there any work arounds?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add

```
.content .product-data { display: inline-block; }
```

The issue will get fixed in firefox

Comment: That almost works, then the caption is just a little bit too wide rather than much too wide!